# What linux permissions are needed for SystemProperties.set to work? (android)

Tags: android, linux, embedded-linux

What linux permissions are needed for SystemProperties.set to work? (android)

I am writing an app that runs in system/app on an android device.

It is running as

> android:sharedUserId="android.uid.systemui"

in Android.mk

> LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

However, I am finding that I cannot create, write or set a property.
In the console, I can do a getprop, setprop. 
However, my program cannot create it.

> ls -l /data/property/

shows it does not exist.

```
        Slog.d(TAG, "key is not set, will set APPLE");
        SystemProperties.set(keyName, favorite);
        if(SystemProperties.get(keyName).equals(favorite)) {
            Slog.d(TAG, keyName + " = " + SystemProperties.get(keyName));
        } else {
            Slog.e(TAG, "setting SystemProperties failed. value written = " + SystemProperties.get(keyName));
        }
```

logcat:

```
Line 1365: D/MyTag( 2593): keyName: persist.fruit.user.favorite
Line 1373: D/MyTag( 2593): keyName has value []
Line 1377: D/MyTag( 2593): key is not set, will set APPLE
Line 1381: E/MyTag( 2593): setting SystemProperties failed. value written =
```

evidently perhaps it is a matter of insufficient permissions - but which ones?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had accepted fadden's answer but after more exploration, found it was incorrect though it was very helpful in reaching the correct answer.

step 1:
look at the array in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-release/init/property_service.c

```
{ "persist.sys.",     AID_SYSTEM,   0 },
```

the name of your property should begin with the same key string in the array.
thus I had to change my property name to   "persist.sys.fruit.user.favorite"

step 2:
in your android manifest file, run as user id mentioned in the array above.

```
<manifest android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" >
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends.  In the 4.4 "KitKat" release, the list was contained in init's [property_service.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-release/init/property_service.c) (look around line 65).  You can see, for example, that properties named `debug.*` can be updated by the "system" or "shell" user.  (The mapping of system-recognized user IDs to numeric values can be found in [android_filesystem_config.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-release/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h).)

Some properties, such as `ro.*`, `persist.*`, and `ctl.*`, have additional restrictions or special behaviors.

In Android 5.0 "Lollipop", the list moved, but the behavior is the same.

Use `adb shell ps` to see what user ID your app is running under.  If it's not `system` or `shell`, it won't be able to set system properties.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My permission `persist.fruit.user.favorite` is not in the list in property_service.c If I understand correctly, are you saying that I would have to edit the file and add my `persist.fruit.user.favorite`?

Comment: I am using 4.4 Kitkat

Comment: The system property mechanism is complicated and subject to change.  I think you should seriously consider not using system properties for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I found the correct way to get it to work - see my answer below

Comment: "in Android 5.0 "Lollipop", the list moved" - where has it moved to out of interest?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** The rules on Android 5+ are more or less the same as for Android 4.4. Check the whitelist from the accepted answer and use a system app for writing sysprops.

---

Since Android 5 access to system properties is controlled only by SELinux policies. Depending on *source security context* (where you're calling from) you will have access to different system properties, which live in a designated *target security context*. A system service running in *system server* has more access than an app running with shared system UID - a *system app*.

The rules consist of several files:

- `property_contexts` - maps system property prefixes to SELinux contexts
- `shell.te` - specifies (among other) which properties are settable by ADB shell (or an app with shell UID)
- `system_app.te` - specifies which properties are settable by a system app (an app with system UID)
- `system_server.te` - specifies which properties are accessible from the system server

Context files are available on the device in location that varies with system version. `*.te` files are compiled to a binary file.

The default values are stored in AOSP repositories and both the values and the location changed over the years.

#### Lollipop

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sepolicy/+/lollipop-release/property_contexts
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sepolicy/+/lollipop-release/system_app.te
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sepolicy/+/lollipop-release/shell.te

#### Nougat

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/nougat-release/property_contexts
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/nougat-release/system-app.te
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/nougat-release/shell.te

#### Oreo

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/oreo-release/private/property_contexts
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/oreo-release/public/property.te
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/oreo-release/public/system_app.te
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/oreo-release/public/shell.te

### Notes

Generally you'd want to set system properties as a system app with one exception. Only a shell UID app may write `log.tag.` until Pie. A system UID app may also write `log.tag.` since Pie.

`seapp_contexts` defines SELinux contexts for apps. On Pie you can't *run* an app with shell system UID.

For more information see https://source.android.com/security/selinux/images/SELinux_Treble.pdf